# Remove duplicates in one column based on another column where there is a hierarchy

Tags: r, filter, duplicates

I have a data frame like this:

```
dat1 <- data.frame(Unit = c("a","a","b","c","c","c","d"), Habitat = c("choppy sands","sands","meadow","sands","meadow","choppy sands","choppy sands"), Litter = c(3.7,3.4,5.6,2.1,3.6,7.5,1.2))

>dat1
  Unit      Habitat Litter
1    a choppy sands    3.7
2    a        sands    3.4
3    b       meadow    5.6
4    c        sands    2.1
5    c       meadow    3.6
6    c choppy sands    7.5
7    d choppy sands    1.2
```

I want to find and remove duplicate rows based on Unit where the single row to keep for each value of Unit depends on a hierarchy of values in Habitat. If there are duplicate rows based on Unit, a row where Habitat = "meadow" takes first priority, then a row where Habitat = "choppy sands", then a row where Habitat = "sands". So the resulting data frame would look like this:

```
  Unit      Habitat Litter
1    a choppy sands    3.7
2    b       meadow    5.6
3    c       meadow    3.6
4    d choppy sands    1.2
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `forcats` (both in the `tidyverse` system of packages), you could do something like this:

```
dat2 <- 
    dat1 %>%
    mutate(Habitat = fct_relevel(Habitat, c('meadow', 'choppy sands', 'sands'), after=0L)) %>%
    group_by(Unit) %>%
    filter(as.numeric(Habitat) == min(as.numeric(Habitat)))
```

This gives the desired output.  The idea is that you make `Habitat` a factor variable and encode your hierarchy in the levels of this variable.  Then, (within each `Unit` group), you keep the rows that have the highest priority `Habitat` by filtering using the `as.numeric(Habitat) == min(as.numeric(Habitat))` rule.

Comment: You could also just use `slice(1)` instead of your `filter`, reduce the code and logic required.

Comment: @r2evans wouldn't that assume the dataframe is sorted within each group?  I guess you could do some kind of `arrange` first and it would still be easier to understand the code but maybe not reduce the logic so much.

Comment: You are assuming (I don't see it in the question) that the OP prefers minimum values of multiple are found. That may not be the case, so I suggested taking the first.

Comment: I am only taking the minimum of `Habitat`, not of `Litter`.  If there were multiple rows for `Unit == a` and `Habitat == 'choppy sands'`, my version would return them all.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution.  I used the `factor` function to set the preferred order for the habitat.  Then ordering the dataframe by Unit and Habitat. Finally removed the duplicates leaving the first row of the unique Units.

```
dat1 <- data.frame(Unit = c("a","a","b","c","c","c","d"), Habitat = c("choppy sands","sands","meadow","sands","meadow","choppy sands","choppy sands"), Litter = c(3.7,3.4,5.6,2.1,3.6,7.5,1.2))

#Use the factor function to order the Habitat in the preferred order
dat1$Habitat<-factor(dat1$Habitat, levels= c("meadow", "choppy sands","sands"))

#order by Unit then by preferred Habitat
dat1<-dat1[order(dat1$Unit, dat1$Habitat),]

#Should retain the first unique row for each Unit
dat1[!duplicated(dat1$Unit),]
```

Comment: If you don't want to convert to/from `factor`, you can use `order(match(Habitat, c("meadow",...), nomatch=99))` to sort (99 was arbitrarily above the length of the vector).